# Get JSON data from ejs view to controller

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

Here is my server.js,

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
var cons = require('consolidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.engine('html', cons.ejs);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get("/getAllData", function(req, res) {
    GPSDataSchemaModel.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
            res.render("index.ejs", {
                dbData: result
            });
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                error: 'Error'
            })
        )}
    })
})

app.get("/onmap", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Query type: " + typeof(req.query))
    console.log("Body type: " + typeof(req.body))
    console.log("Parameters type: " + typeof(req.params))
    res.send(req.query)
})
```

here is my index.ejs,

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                          
                            <td>In Map</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                     <% for(var i=0; i < dbData.length; i++) { %>                        
                     <tr>
                     <td><a href="/onmap?<%= JSON.stringify(dbData[i]) %>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Map</a></td>  
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The data format in mongoDb is like below,

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58ad111590c50e1ca0c1f352"
},
"deviceID": "group-6-GPS",
"deviceTime": "04:41:37",
"deviceDate": "2016/06/07",
"receiveTime": "10:18:29",
"receiveDate": "2017/02/22",
"latitude": 17.08,
"longitude": 15.07,
"fix": 0,
"satellites": 0,
"altitude": null,
"deviceSpeed": 0,
"devicecourse": 0,
"deviceVariation": null,
"__v": 0
}
```

After clicking on the Map button I get the data like this,

```
{
{"_id":"58ad111590c50e1ca0c1f352","deviceID":"group-6-GPS","deviceTime":"04:41:37","deviceDate":"2016/06/07","receiveTime":"10:18:29","receiveDate":"2017/02/22","latitude":"17.08","longitude":"15.07","fix":0,"satellites":0,"altitude":null,"deviceSpeed":0,"devicecourse":0,"deviceVariation":null,"__v":0}: ""
}
```

Please note data format of the above two are not same.

I need to access the **latitude** and **longitude** from the second data. How can I do that? Or, what I can do to get the second data as JSON?

Comment: @p0k8_ Thanks a lot. It did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to provide the latitude and longitutude in your query then, below is the code which provide url as

`http://localhost:3000/onmap?latitude=17.08&longitude=15.07`

and the parsed query will be `{"latitude":"17.08","longitude":"15.07"}`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>                          
        <td>In Map</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <% for(var i=0; i < dbData.length; i++) { %>                        
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/onmap?latitude=<%= dbData[i].latitude %>&longitude=<%= dbData[i].longitude %>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Map</a></td>  
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```